# Why some methods in android studio are marked with a line on it?

Tags: android

Some methods are marked with a line on it. Is this some kind of error ?? this thing bothers me but the applications work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Deprecated methods. That means that there are newer alternative methods available to be used which are more compatible. Deprecated methods do work, but Google does not guarantee their proper functioning. And support for those methods may be ended in future versions of android.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what I should use instead?

Comment: I usually find alternatives by just googling it.

Comment: Me too, I just wanted to know if there is a built-in feature in Android Studio that would tell me.

Answer (score 4):

They are deprecated. Consider using ones who aren't.